# Excel Array Formula in Named Range to Return List of Sequential Numbers

Tags: arrays, excel, named-ranges

I would like to use an array in the formula of a Named Range to return a list of sequential numbers. So instead of having a list of numbers on an actual worksheet, they are produced by an array formula and stored in a Named Range to be used as a Data Validation List for a dropdown menu.

**I  already have:**

[image]

**I would like:**

[image]

So the goal is to substitute listing the sequential numbers in A1:A10, which a Named Range would reference, with an array that produces the sequential numbers and is the reference of the Named Range.

I spent several hours Googling for an answer to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The formula I supplied (then deleted) would work for a named range but the named range isn't going to resolve in a data validation list. I will look into this a little more but right now I suspect you cannot use a dynamic formula in a data validation list in the way you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Define `Numbers` as `=ROW($A$1:$A$1000)`.